# Am I allowed to surface mount a hardwire LED Driver

Tags: led

I'm installing new LEDs for under cabinet lighting.  The kit I'm looking at comes with a hardwired transformer/driver.

[image: Hardwired LED driver module]

It has clips for screwing it to a wall or the underside of a cabinet.  But one side takes 120v and I would think that then code would require this doo-dad to be in a metal enclosure.

Can I mount this or does code in the USA require devices like this one to be placed in an enclosure ?

Comment: The fact that it's UL Listed (and not RU Recognized) is a very good sign.  That means it's approved for direct installation in homes (not as a component) and UL will have approved the labeling and instructions *as part of the approval*.   What does the labeling and instructions tell you about installation?  You must follow them (NEC 110.3B).

Comment: Once you put the cover back on, the wiring will be enclosed.  So you should be looking at how the other end of the 120v wire is connected to the source, a plug, or J-Box

Comment: As long as exposed conductors are unreachable by fingers and screw contacts secure tightly with gap barrier. No problem.  A 5 lb pull test should not affect the connection if OK.

Comment: Is there a cableclamp or knockout in the AC line side cover provided with the unit?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica; Thank you for the code reference.  When I get the unit I will check the instructions.  I asked the re-seller of the unit and they said it was ok ( FWiW )

Comment: @grbonk If you mail-ordered it, 99% of what's on Amazon Marketplace, and 99.9% of what comes ePacket from China, is dangerous junk that must never be used in AC mains wiring.  Best to acquire AC equipment either from responsible local shops e.g. electrical supply or via the mail-order arms of major bricks-n-mortar home stores (e.g. Homedepot.com, Lowes.com.  Walmart.com is not because they include Amazon stuff in their catalog).  That said, it's *rare* to see fake UL listings; you can always call UL with the file number and see if it's legit.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- indeed, I looked up the file number in the OP's photo on UL Product iQ (I'd post the link here, but you'd need to register on that site to see it) and it's legit -- to be fair, that's no guarantee that you'll get what's in the photo, though